#  Is U(n) a normal subgroup of SO(2n)?

Tags: lie-groups, gr.group-theory

U(n) is the group of n by n unitary complex matrices and SO(2n) is the group of 2n by 2n real orthogonal matrices with determinant 1.So far I can show that how to get an injective  group homomorphism from U(n) to SO(2n). This shows that U(n) is isomorphic to a subgroup of SO(2n).But I have no idea whether U(n) is normal in SO(2n)? If someone could explain this to me or just point out some reference for me,I will appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked with the references at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_group ? By the way, your tagging is misleading: group-theory and lie-groups are definitely more efficient.

Comment: One of the reasons this is so difficult may be that $U(n)$ is not a normal subgroup of $SO(n)$ at all (unless $n=1$): when $n>2$ the Lie algebra $so(2n)$ is simple and does not have any ideals and when $n=2$ the only ideals are copies of $su(2)$, not $u(2)$.

Comment: ..that is $U(n)$ is not a normal subgroup of $SO(2n)$..

Comment: Finding an injection from a group $A$ to a group $B$ doesn't show that $A$ is a subgroup of $B$; it shows that $A$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $B$. The distinction is important (in general, though I don't know about the particular case you ask about), e.g., the group $D_8$ of symmetries of a square has several subgroups isomorphic to the cyclic group of order 2, but one of those subgroups is normal in $D_8$ and the others aren't. 

Comment: Following algori's observations, shouldn't the title of the question perhaps be changed to remove the word "why"?

Comment: Thanks. The answers clarify many things for me. The reason that I ask this question is that I am confused about what's the meaning of the quotient $SO(2n)/U(n)$ if $U(n)$ is not isomorphic to a normal subgroup of $SO(2n)$?

Comment: The quotient SO(2n)/U(n) simply means to take the (right) coset space, which is NOT a group in this case.  However, using the natural map $\pi:SO(2n)\rightarrow SO(2n)/U(n)$, we put a topology on $SO(2n)/U(n)$ which turns $SO(2n)/U(n)$ into a (topological) manifold.  Further, we can declare $\pi$ to be a submersion which puts a differentiable structure on $SO(2n)/U(n)$, making it a smooth manifold.  (All of this applies equally well to any $G/H$ with $G$ and $H$ compact.  If things are not compact, one must be a little careful.)

Comment: Huichi -- if $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, normal or not, one can consider the set $G/H$ formed by the left cosets $gH,g\in G$. If $G$ is a Lie group and $H$ is a closed subgroup (hence, automatically a Lie subgroup), then $G/H$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $\dim G-\dim H$.

Comment: Jason -- indeed one must be careful when considering actions of non-compact groups but in this case there aren't any nasty surprises: the quotient of a any Lie group by any closed subgroup is a manifold.

Comment: @algori - Thank you!  Unfortunately (fortunately?), I really only work with compact spaces so I often forget when theorems can be extended from "compact" to, say, "closed subgroup", or "proper map", etc.

Comment: @Jason: I know that's equivalent, but isn't $G/H$ technically the left coset space $\{aH\}$?  The left cosets are the ones that have a left action of $G$.

Comment: @Greg: You're right!  If I could edit the comment I would!